# Formidable gives unhandledRejection: FormidableError: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START ERROR

Tags: next.js, formidable

So I'm currently trying to create some kind of an API that updates a table in MySQL database and I'm using Formidable package for form data parsing. The update may and may not use a file to replace but in the case where there is no file uploaded. It gives me this error

```
error - unhandledRejection: FormidableError: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START
    at MultipartParser._flush (H:\Files2022\ChronoMedia\chronoapp\node_modules\formidable\src\parsers\Multipart.js:75:9)
    at MultipartParser.final [as _final] (node:internal/streams/transform:133:25)
    at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:696:27)
    at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:725:7)
    at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:735:5)
    at MultipartParser.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:633:5)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (H:\Files2022\ChronoMedia\chronoapp\node_modules\formidable\src\Formidable.js:211:24)
    at Readable.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 1012,
  httpCode: 400
}
```

Here is my code

```
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();                  
                    
                    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        const {title,content,category,currentPath} = fields;
                        let query = `UPDATE articles set ArticleTitle='${title}', ArticleContent='${content}', ArticleCategory=${category} where ArticleId=${aid}`;
                        try{
                            await connection.execute(query);
                        }catch(err){
                            throw err;
                        }

                        if(files.image){
                            fs.unlink(process.cwd()+"/public"+currentPath);

                            var oldpath = files.image.filepath;
                            fileName = "/public/images/" + uuid4()+"."+MIME_TYPE_MAP[files.image.mimetype];
                            let saveName = fileName.replace('/public','');
                            var newpath = process.cwd()+fileName;
                            fs.copyFile(oldpath, newpath,fs.constants.COPYFILE_EXCL, function (err) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                            });

                            let query = `UPDATE articles set ArticleImage='${saveName}' where ArticleId=${aid}`;
                            try{
                                await connection.execute(query);
                            }catch(err){
                                throw err;
                            }

                        }

                        
                    });
```

I tried looking for a way to make formidable ignores files but it seems not working.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution, anyone please?

Comment: Don't concat user input to make a db query

Comment: I know this is not your question but if you want help then provide readable and correct code at the very least